# Tree of Life in the midst of the garden?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-bereishit, trees, gan-eden

How should the following phrase be interpreted?

> וְעֵץ הַחַיִּים בְּתוֹךְ הַגָּן

(Genesis [2:9](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%91_%D7%98))

Does this mean

1. The [Tree of Life] (which is) in the garden

or does it mean

2. The Tree of [Life within the garden]?

Comment: The cantillation strongly suggests the former.

Comment: Two more conceivable possibilities: "a tree of {those who live in the garden}" and "{a tree of those who live} which is in the garden". (_Chayim_ is not only "life" but the masculine plural present of "to live".)

Comment: @msh210 No. That's [choyim](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=34229&st=&pgnum=71) (as opposed to chayyim). IINM

Comment: @DoubleAA I believe you're mistaken. Check the verse "_v'atem had'vekim..._" to be sure.

Answer (score 6):

Verse 3:22 would seem to indicate the former:

> וַיֹּאמֶר יְהוָה אֱלֹהִים, הֵן הָאָדָם הָיָה כְּאַחַד מִמֶּנּוּ, לָדַעַת, טוֹב וָרָע; וְעַתָּה פֶּן-יִשְׁלַח יָדוֹ, וְלָקַח גַּם מֵעֵץ הַחַיִּים, וְאָכַל, וָחַי לְעֹלָם

Here, עץ החיים is not modified with בתוך הגן, so evidently that is not part of its name, but rather a geographical indicator.